# What do I need to use SQLite in Java?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm using SQLite for a simple attendance tracking application to be implemented in Java. I am using the driver found in http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc and I want to know if i need the dll's still or if i only need the jar i retrieved from the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar you retrieved from the site should be sufficient. Toward the bottom of the page you cite, it says:

Run with:

```
java -cp .:sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Test
```

I just (re)tested that jar, on an Ubuntu system and on my Snow Leopard system. The same jar worked fine in both places.

Comment: thanks. i was just worried cause i read somewhere that you had to include the dll in the folder.

Comment: The JAR includes the DLLs, at least for "common" environments. Use `jar tvf sqlitejdbc.jar` to see exactly which ones it has.